# How to get unique value in FormArray reactive form in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a stackblitz app to demonstrate my question here: https://angular-ry1vc1.stackblitz.io/

I have formArray values on a select HTML list. Whenever a user changes the selection, it should display the selected value on the page. The problem is how can I display only the current selection and it should **NOT** overwrite the value selected previously. I wonder how to use the `key` to make the placeholder of the values unique. TIA

`form.html`

```
<form [formGroup]="heroForm" novalidate class="form">
  <section formArrayName="league" class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Heroes</h3>
    <div class="form-inline" *ngFor="let h of heroForm.controls.league.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <label>Name</label>
      <select (change)="onSelectingHero($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [value]="hero.id" class="form-control">{{hero.name}}</option>
      </select> <hr />
      <div>
        Hero detail: {{selectedHero.name}}
      </div> <hr />
    </div>
    <button (click)="addMoreHeroes()" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add more heroes</button>
  </section>
</form>
```

`component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  heroes = [];
  heroForm: FormGroup;
  selectedHero;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.heroForm = fb.group({
      league: fb.array([
        this.loadHeroes(),
        this.loadHeroes(),
        this.loadHeroes()
      ])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listHeroes();
  }

  public addMoreHeroes() {
    const control = this.heroForm.get('league') as FormArray;
    control.push(this.loadHeroes());
  }

  public loadHeroes() {
    return this.fb.group(
      {
        id: this.heroes[0],
        name: '',
        level: '',
        skill: '',
      }
    );
  }  

  public listHeroes() {
    this.heroes = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Superman'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Batman'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Aquaman'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Wonderwoman'
      }      
    ];
  }

  public onSelectingHero(heroId) {
    this.heroes.forEach((hero) => {
      if(hero.id === +heroId) {
        this.selectedHero = hero;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the aim of this is to show only the selected hero by array element instead of replace all the selected values then you can get some help using the array form elements.

**A.**  The `onSeletingHero` and `selectedHero` are not necessary, I replaced that using the form value through `formControlName` attribute, in this example the `id` control is the `select`.  The `h.value.id` is the way to get the selected value id.

```
    <select formControlName="id">
        <option *ngFor="let hero of heroes;" [value]="hero.id" class="form-control">{{hero.name}}</option>
      </select> <hr />
      <div>
        Hero detail: {{getHeroById(h.value.id).name}}
      </div> <hr />
    </div>
```

**B.**  In order to get the selected hero I added a `getHeroById` method.

```
  getHeroById(id: number) {
    return id ? this.heroes.find(x => x.id === +id) : {id: 0, name: ''};
  }
```

Hope this information solve your question.  Cheers

Comment: What is `h.value.id` in the `getHeroById(h.value.id).name` ?

Comment: `h` comes from `*ngFor="let h of heroForm....` h is a form group element of the form array.  `h.value` return a json that represents your form model in this case is `{id: x, name: xxx, level: xx, skill: xx}` and `h.value.id` means that I want to read the id element from that json.  `getHeroById(h.value.id).name`  is a method invocation to retrieve the selected hero, but only the name and the input parameter is `h.value.id` which is the selected id.

Comment: got that! Thanks supppperb!